# Ruby spec expected: 1 time with any arguments received: 0 times with any arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec

Getting an error running my spec and I am guessing that it may be that update_all has been deprecated.  I must be missing something obvious

**Code:**

```
def update_the_members_email
    self.the_members.update_all(email: self.email)
end
```

**Spec:**

```
describe 'update_the_members_email' do

    describe 'when after_save is triggered' do
       let(:updated_email) { Faker::Internet.safe_email }
        before do
          user.email = updated_email
          user.save
        end
      it 'triggers update_all' do
        expect(user).to receive_message_chain(:the_members, :update_all).with({ :email => updated_email })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Error:**

`1) User update_the_members_email when after_save is triggered triggers update_all
Failure/Error: expect(user).to receive_message_chain(:the_members, :update_all).with({ :email => new_email })

```
  [....].the_members(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

`

I have tried using update_column instead of update_all.   Tried a few other ways of specing this out.  Spent a ton of time researching.

Comment: Could you show how `update_the_members_email` is called? It's implied there's an after_save callback.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `update_the_members_email` is called by an after save callback...

[The mock](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-12/docs/basics/expecting-messages) has to be set up before the call. `before` happens *before* the test. So `user.email` happens *before* you've set your expectation. The expectation never sees it.

```
describe 'after save callbacks' do
  it 'updates all members email when the email is updated' do
    updated_email = Faker::Internet.safe_email

    expect(user).to receive_message_chain(:the_members, :update_all)
      .with(email: updated_email )

    user.update!(email: updated_email)
  end
end
```

Note that mocking is not necessary here. Just make sure the user has some members and test directly.

```
describe 'after save callbacks' do
  let(:updated_email) { Faker::Internet.safe_email }

  context 'when the user email is updated' do
    before do
      user.update!(email: updated_email)
    end

    it 'updates all members email when the email is updated' do
      # I'm assuming the user has members.
      expect(user.the_members).to all have_attributes(email: updated_email)
    end
  end
end
```

---

- There's no need to append self to method calls. `the_members.update_all(email: email)`
- Use the Ruby 2.0 style of passing named arguments: `with(email: updated_email)`
- Try [rubocop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.40/index.html) and [rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rspec) to inform you about good style.